# Excel 2010 Formula to replace numbers

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a list of results that may return a decimal value between `0` and `5`. For business purposes I need to force Excel to replace the number as follows:

- Any decimal value between `0` and `1` needs to show as the whole number `0`
- Any decimal value between `1` and `2` needs to show as the whole number `1`
- Any decimal value between `2` and `3` needs to show as the whole number `2`
- Any decimal value between `3` and `4` needs to show as the whole number `3`
- Any decimal value between `4` and `4.5`needs to show as the whole number `4`
- Any decimal value between `4.5` and `5` needs to show the actual decimal value.

So, if the decimal value is `1.5`, I want Excel to show it in the cell as `1`. Or, if the decimal value is `4.5`, I want excel to show it as `4.5`.

I've tried using the following nested `IF` function (in this example the number to replaces is in cell L28):

`=IF(L28>=4.5,L28,IF(L28<4.5>=4,"4",IF(L28=4,"4",IF(L28<4>=3,"3",IF(L28<2>=1,"2",IF(L28<1>=0,"0"))))))`

However for some reason it works on values `4` or greater, but for anything `<4` still shows `4`, and I can't figure out why.

Should I be doing this in VBA instead?

Thanks in advance, and I'm hoping I explained this clearly...

Comment: The reason your formula returns `4` for all values `<4` is due to the logical condition `L28<4.5>=4`. You are trying to specify two logical conditions, but -- assuming `L28 = 3.3` -- Excel is evaluating `3.3 < 4.5 = TRUE`, and then `TRUE >= 4 = TRUE`, and therefore returning `4` and never proceeding to the rest of the nested `IF()` statements. For some reason, Excel treats text (including `TRUE`/`FALSE`) as greater than numbers, so your condition fails. To use this construct, you need `AND(L28<4.5, L28>=4)` -- but @Brian Cohan's answer is better.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why it was returning 4, I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why the [`FLOOR()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/floor.php) function exists.

```
=IF(A1<=4.5,FLOOR(A1, 1),A1)
```